# Javascript Fetch is always pending?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code:

```
function nk(args) {   
              return fetch(`${ourUrl}/assets/physics.json`)
                    .then(result => result.json()) // I'm not exactly sure why this is necessary?
                    .then(nk_json => { // From now on it's just processing the data I need.
                        console.log('nk_json:', nk_json);
                        const array = nk_json[args[0]];
                        const base_formula = array[0];
                        const definitions = array[1].join('<br>');

                        if (args[0] === 'list') {
                            return [ object.keys(nk_json).join('<br>') ];
                        } else {
                            console.log("We're here!");
                            return [
                                `base formula for ${bi(args[0])}: ${base_formula}`,
                                `contextual definitions: ${definitions}`
                            ];
                        }
                    })
}
```

I have an issue where, whatever I do, it always returns a Pending promise.

```
Promise {<pending>} 
[[Prototype]]: Promise
[[PromiseState]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseResult]]: Object
```

I have tried using async, splitting it up into multiple functions, and everything seems to fail, and still return a promise. The array (nk_json) seems to be working, because the console.log returns it perfectly. The issue is the return statement at the bottom. The "We're here" also gets printed perfectly, so the code works. I have tried multiple combinations of returning the code outside the function, or saving the return in a variable and returning that, and a few things, but the main issue just seems to be that the `fetch()` just returns a promise.
I've been struggling with this for days and I can't fix it, so pls help

Comment: `.then(result => result.json()) // I'm not exactly sure why this is necessary?`  Because your wanting `json`, and not `text` or `blob`

Comment: `return fetch` you're returning the promise itself, so your calling code can add its own `.then` etc.

Comment: It will only EVER return a Promise. You cannot return anything that is not a Promise. You just need to learn how to work with promises (eg. use `async/await` or use `.then()`). All functions marked with `async` (which is needed if you want to `await` the `nk()` function) also return a Promise. So you must learn how to work with promises and cannot ever escape from a Promise

Answer (score 1):

You are returning a promise, so it will give you pending promise when calling the function.

You need to wait for the promise to fulfill or got rejected to get the data.

```js
nk(args)
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```